# Mask a Css Animation in a SVG path

Tags: css, animation, svg, mask

i'm trying to reproduce this effect

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojvMNX

```
@mixin foggy-background($x, $y) {
background:
  radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 40%) 400px+$x*3 300px+$y*2 no-repeat,
  radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,255,255,.5) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 40%) 0px+$x*3 0px+$y*2 no-repeat,
  radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,255,255,.6) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%) 50px+$x*2 300px+$y no-repeat,
  radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 40%) -200px+$x -150px+$y no-repeat,
  #000;
}

@keyframes animate {
   // with a bit more love you can get better results :)
 0% {
    @include foggy-background(-400, -300);
 }

 100% {
    @include foggy-background(200, 500);
 }
}
```

in my website using as mask not a Text, but my own SVG and this is what i get:

https://jsfiddle.net/6xhca8mu/1/

```
<svg version="1.1" id="magritte" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         viewBox="-461 463 100 100"xml:space="preserve">

    <path fill="#FFF"  d="M-381.1,523.6l-2-5.2l0,0l-4.7-3.7L-398,511l-7.4-7.4l-0.3-2l1.4-2.9l0,0l-0.3-3.1l1.9-1.4l1-6.6v-0.1l-0.8-1
        l-1.1,0.4l0.2-0.7l1.3-0.1l2.8-1.4l1.5-1.6l-2.1-1.2h-0.1l-2.6,1.1l-0.9-0.6l-1.5-10.9l0,0l-1.7-1.8h-13.1l-1.2,1.1l-2.2,8.8h-0.9
        l1.1,2.1l-0.5,1.5l-4.1-0.6l-1.5,1.5l2.3,1.5l4.1,1.6l-0.2,0.5l-1.4-0.8l0.6,5.1l0,0l1.8,2.7l0.4,4.7l0,0l1.5,2l-0.7,1.9l-6.1,7.1
        l-8.6,3.2l0,0l-4,4.8l-3.3,7.6l0.1,8h0.1l-0.1,0.1l11.1,6.4l12.3,16l5.8-13.1l0.6-18.7l5-8.6l1.4-4.2l0,0l1-3.1v-1.1l0,0v-0.1v-0.2
        l0,0v-3.5l7.2,7.4l10.3,3.5l4.6,3.6l2,5.2l1.8,15.4h0.2L-381.1,523.6z M-409,511.8l-3.6-0.1l2.4-3.7l1,3.3l0,0L-409,511.8z
         M-409,511l-1-3.2l4.2-2.1l0.2-1v2.8L-409,511z M-403.7,486L-403.7,486L-403.7,486l-3.8,0.5l-2.2-2l0,0l-1.8,0.1l-0.1-2h3.5l4.9,3.3
        L-403.7,486z M-420.7,487.3l3.8-2.6h2l-0.2,1.9l-1.1,1.9l-1,0.8c-0.3,0.2-0.7,0.5-1,0.8l-0.8,0.5l-2.8,0.2l1-1.5L-420.7,487.3z
         M-414.1,479.8l0.6-0.6l0.4,2.1l-0.6,4.1l0.2-4l0,0L-414.1,479.8z M-413.1,483.3l0.2,0.6l0,0l0,0l1.4,4.4c-0.6-0.2-1.3-0.3-1.9-0.3
        c-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4,0L-413.1,483.3z M-413,482.9l0.2-1.2l0.9,1l0.1,1.9l-0.9-0.7L-413,482.9L-413,482.9z M-414.1,488.1
        c-0.7,0.1-1.4,0.2-2,0.5l1.2-1.9l0.3-2.1l0.9-1.3L-414.1,488.1z M-418,490.2l1-0.8c1.1-0.7,2.3-1.1,3.7-1.1c3.7,0,6.7,3,6.7,6.7
        s-3,6.7-6.7,6.7c-3.7,0-6.7-3-6.7-6.7C-420.1,493.1-419.3,491.4-418,490.2z M-411.2,488.4L-411.2,488.4l-1.3-4.2l0.8,0.6v0.1
        l1.9-0.1l2.2,2l2.2,2.3l0.8,3.1h-2.5C-407.9,490.4-409.4,489-411.2,488.4z M-420.8,470.9l1.1-1.1h12.9l1.6,1.7l1.5,11l1.1,0.7
        l2.5-1.1l1.8,1l-1.3,1.4l-2.7,1.4h-0.5l-5.3-3.5l0,0h-3.6l-1.1-1.1l-0.5-2.5l-1.1,0.9l0.7,1.7l-1.3,1.2l-4.8-2.1l-3.2-0.8
        L-420.8,470.9z M-423.7,479.9h0.5l3.3,0.9l3.9,1.7l-2.3,1.8l-3.4-0.9l-1.1-1.6L-423.7,479.9z M-426.7,485.4l-2-1.3l1.2-1.2l4.2,0.6
        l0.5-1.4l0.9,1.6l3.7,0.9l2.5-2l0,0l0.7,0.3l1.3-1.1l-0.1,1.2l-0.1-0.1l-1,1.5h-2.2l-3.9,2.6h-1.5L-426.7,485.4z M-419.6,501.4
        l-1.5-2l-0.5-4.8l0,0l-1.8-2.5l-0.5-4.7l1,0.7l0.4-0.8l1.5,0.1l-0.1,1.9l-1.2,1.9l3.3-0.2c-0.9,1.2-1.4,2.6-1.4,4.2c0,3.8,3.1,7,7,7
        c3.8,0,7-3.1,7-7c0-0.9-0.2-1.8-0.5-2.7h2.7l-0.9-3.5l-2.1-2.2l3.4-0.5l-0.2,1l1.4-0.6l0.7,0.8l-1,6.4l-2,1.4l0.3,3.3l-1.4,2.8
        l0.4,2.3l-0.4,1.8l-4.2,2.1l-2.3,3.7l-1.7-3.4l-3.9-1.3l-2.3-3.2L-419.6,501.4z M-415.6,511.1l1.3-2.7l1.5,3.3l0,0l-3.5,0.6
        L-415.6,511.1L-415.6,511.1z M-420.5,503.8l2.2,3.1l3.8,1.3l-1.4,2.8l-2.3-1l-1.4-2l-1-3.9L-420.5,503.8z M-420.8,504.1l1,4l0.6,3
        l-4.5,7.5l-2.9-8L-420.8,504.1z M-413,524.5l-18.2,15.5l3.7-14.7l8.3-13.8L-413,524.5z M-418.8,511.8l1.9,1.7l2.8,0.9l0.4,2.3
        l-1,3.7L-418.8,511.8z M-439.4,518.7l4-4.7l8.5-3.2l2.9,8.2l-3.7,6.1l-14.7,0.8L-439.4,518.7z M-442.4,533.9l-0.1-7.8l14.7-0.8
        l-3.7,14.8L-442.4,533.9z M-419.3,555.9l-11.9-15.5l9.1-7.7l8.3,10.7L-419.3,555.9z M-413.7,543l-8.2-10.6l8.9-7.6L-413.7,543z
         M-408,516l-2,3.5l-1.4-2.9l0.3-2.1l3.3-1.3l1.1-1L-408,516z M-405.6,508.7l-1,3l-1.4,1.3l-3.4,1.4l-0.3,2.3l1.5,3l-2.6,4.5
        l-1.6-3.4l1.1-4.1l-0.5-2.5l-2.9-0.9l-2.3-2.1l-0.5-2.6l1.1,1.6l2.4,1l-0.8,1.4l4-0.7l4.2,0.1l-0.3-0.8l3.3-3.3
        C-405.6,507.9-405.6,508.7-405.6,508.7z"/>
    </svg>
```

How can i fix this? Thanks so much for any reply.

Comment: The same technique is probably not going to work on an SVG.  If you switch it around you might have more success.  Instead of trying to apply an animated background mask to an SVG, try applying an animated background to a `<div>` and then masking it with your magritte SVG.

Comment: Thanks to your comment! but how can i use that SVG as a Mask? i have to edit the SVG code? I've done it by myself with illustrator so i can edit it as i wish, but a suggestion will be so helpful!

that's how it works when i remove the 
  -webkit-background-clip: text;  from the CSS file





https://jsfiddle.net/6xhca8mu/1/